# MySQL SSL Remote Connection Error: Unable to get Private Key

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I am attempting to write a PHP script (hosted on a VPS with GoDaddy) that connects to a remote MySQL database (hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance) using SSL.

I generated some certs (as per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-certs.html) and configured *my.cnf* on the remote/server database like so:

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca      =/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert    =/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key     =/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

[client]
ssl-ca      =/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert    =/etc/mysql/client-cert.pem
ssl-key     =/etc/mysql/client-key.pem
```

The configuration is working on the remote/server side (that is, a php script running locally to the remote database is able to establish a connection using the generated SSL certs).

However, while I can make an unsecured connection between the PHP script hosted on the VPS and the remote database, I get an error when I try to establish an SSL connection between the same two systems.

If I attempt to connect to the remote database via the command line using:

```
mysql -h hostIP --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem –u ssluser –p
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: Unable to get private key
```

I get the same error when I attempt to connect to the server via the php script using:

```
<?php
 $link = mysqli_init();

 $key   = '/home/userName/etc/mysql/certs/client-key.pem' ; 
 $cert  = '/home/userName/etc/mysql/certs/client-cert.pem'; 
 $ca    = '/home/userName/etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem';
 $capath = NULL;
 $cipher = NULL;

 mysqli_ssl_set ( $link , $key , $cert , $ca , $capath , $cipher );
 mysqli_real_connect ($link, $host, $user, $pass, $schema, 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
?>
```

results in the error:

```
(HY000/2026): SSL connection error: Unable to get private key
```

I have already attempted a fix as per (forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,400856,401127), but making this change results in a "Segmentation fault".

Is there a step that I've missed? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**RESOLVED**:

removed the client-key.pem passphrase using

```
openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out client-key2.pem
```

as per the instructions at [this website](http://www.defcon1.org/html/postfix1.html).

I changed

```
$key   = '/home/userName/etc/mysql/certs/client-key2.pem' ;
```

and

```
mysql -h hostIP --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key2.pem –u ssluser –p
```

but not

```
[client]
ssl-key     =/etc/mysql/client-key.pem
```

Comment: I think the first command should have as an output `client-key2.pem` with a dash, not an underscore.

Comment: You can convert the original key in-place: `openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out client-key.pem`

Comment: as at OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, this command demands a password and won't complete without it.

Answer (score 3):

I my case, the owner of server-key.pem was root and not mysql.

Answer (score 2):

**'openssl genrsa'** generates key in PKCS #1 format:

```
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    ...

    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

While **'openssl pkey'** or  **openssl  req -newkey.....**  generate it in PKCS #8 format:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- 
... 

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And MySQL Server expects PKCS #1 format.

Adding  RSA after BEGIN and END solved the issue for me.

Check link for detail [mysql forum](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,400856,400856)

Answer (score 2):

For me the key needed to be converted to full rsa format, not just changing the headers:

`openssl rsa -in client.key -out client.key.rsa`

Thanks to [Velkan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/201770/mysql-ssl-error-unable-to-get-private-key) over on dba exchange for that answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs when you pass SSL CA file to SSL Key File in MySQL.

[image: MySQL SSL CA file]